# DirectMessageListenerContainer and SimpleMessageListenerContainer relationship to Rabbit Channels

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-rabbit

When using ***DirectMessageListenerContainer*** with ***consumersPerQueue*** property of 25, I noticed **25** rabbit channels get created per listener container's subscribed queue. The rabbit channel count quickly grows out of hand in our setup, as more queues are added to the listener container dynamically. We had to increase broker channel limit to accommodate the channel growth.

1. What is the relationship between channels and consumers in the DirectMessageListenerContainer. From my observations it appears to be 1 channel per consumer.
2. Does DirectMessageListenerContainer offer any channel pooling/recycling/rebalancing to keep channel growth under control. Specifically for queues that are mostly idle.
3. Does the simple SimpleMessageListenerContainer handle channels pooling differently, since it can dynamically resize the consumer count.

Answer (score 1):

1. The DMLC uses a separate channel for each consumer.
2. No.
3. The SMLC uses one channel per `concurrentConsumers`; since 2.0, each channel is used for multiple consumers (when there is more than one queue listened to).

However dynamically adding or removing queues is much less efficient with the SMLC because the consumer(s) are canceled and re-created when changes are made.

Comment: The main reason is for isolation - with a shared channel, with certain categories of errors, if one consumer causes an error, the channel will be closed by the broker; affecting all the consumers in that channel. We could consider adding an option for a channel per queue, or something similar, in a future release. Please open a GitHub issue.

Comment: What is the best practice for a system where we are going to be dynamically adding/removing queues and want to use channels efficiently so as to not hit the channels_max limit of RabbitMQ?'

Comment: I don't have a good solution for you right now; hence my suggestion to open a new feature request.